# LINQ: Convert Guid to string

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I am getting an exception when I execute this code:

```
var result = from menu in menuBus.GetMenus()
             orderby menu.InternalName
             select new 
             {
                 Value = menu.ID.ToString(),
                 Text = menu.InternalName
             };

var result = allMenus.ToList();
```

The error message says: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a stored expression.

So, I guess that something goes wrong with Value = menu.ID.ToString(). The ID property is defined as GUID (UniqueIdentifier in MS SQL).

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to run the list through another query after querying the database.

```
var result = (from menu in menuBus.GetMenus()
                        orderby menu.InternalName
                        select new 
                        {
                            Value = menu.ID,
                            Text = menu.InternalName
                        }).ToList();


var result2 = (from menu in result select new {Value=menu.Value.ToString(),Text=menu.Text}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't have `.ToString()` in your linq query because linq to entity doesn't know what to do with it (because it can't convert it to an sql statement)... You can have the select part as

```
select new
{
     Value = menu.ID,
     Test = menu.InternalName
}
```

and then just user a foreach loop and copy the values into another list while converting the guid to string

Comment: foreach is not needed here, you can use additional linq to objects query.